# AreEqual comparing objects with ToString

Tags: nunit, assertions

I'm using Assert.AreEqual to compare two objects.  The objects are two different instances of the same class and there is a ToString method in that class.  When I call AreEqual I can see from the debugger that the ToString method gets called (once for each of the two variables).

The ToString method returns *exactly* the same string in each case but still for some reason the AreEqual method returns false.

Why might this be?

The error is

```
Additional information:   Expected: <DeliveryTag: 0, RoutingKey: , Body: test, Headers: test: test, ContentType: text/plain>

  But was:  <DeliveryTag: 0, RoutingKey: , Body: test, Headers: test: test, ContentType: text/plain>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToString` is simply called to report the expected and actual values. It's *not* what determines equality. That's the `Equals(object)` method, which you should be overriding in order to provide the equality semantics you're interested in. (You should consider implementing `IEquatable<T>` as well, but that's slightly separate.)

In short, `Assert.AreEqual` is implemented *something* like:

```
// Somewhat simplified, but right general idea
if (!expected.Equals(actual))
{
    // Note how once we've got here, it's too late... the results
    // of ToString are irrelevant to whether or not we throw an exception
    string expectedText = expected.ToString();
    string actualText = actual.ToString();
    string message = string.Format("Expected: {0}  But was: {1}",
        expectedText, actualText);
    throw new AssertionFailureException(message);
}
```